How much data does Zelle collect?
I know Early Warning Services LLC sees all payments made through Zelle. But do they also collect data on other transactions and accounts with your bank? What are all the privacy/security implications, and risks of using Zelle?

Ask your bank. But I expect they get nothing but what you put through their system.
